# Spark SQL (Databricks) function xpath ignores empty tags in XML

Tags: xpath, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Spark SQL (Databricks) function xpath ignores empty tags in XML. For example for below XML XPATH returns array ["ABC"]. We need it as ["ABC", NULL or empty string] because when we use this along with posexplode_outer, omitting null in XPATH will cause incorrect association.
Is there any option in XPATH to retain nulls? I did not find any detailed documentation for this.

```
SELECT xpath("<PARTY>
                <PARTY_EVENT>
                    <EVENTTYPE>VISITED</EVENTTYPE>
                    <LOCATION>ABC</LOCATION>
                </PARTY_EVENT>
                <PARTY_EVENT>
                    <EVENTTYPE>VISITED</EVENTTYPE>
                    <LOCATION />
                </PARTY_EVENT>
                </PARTY>"
        , '/PARTY/PARTY_EVENT/LOCATION/text()')
```

[image]

Comment: What's xpath expression did you use?

Comment: Just updated that in Question. Thanks @Arseny

Comment: Maybe find the nodes w/o text using `[not(text())]` selector and combine the results with the ones you already find?

Comment: Like `(.../LOCATION|.../LOCATION[not(text())])/text()`

Comment: I think this is an XPATH question, basically. There are some answers to it on the web, just google something like "xpath tag without text return empty string"

Comment: Thanks much for your suggestions.. I am trying this and will post an update soon..

Comment: additing |.../LOCATION[not(text())]) helped. Thanks much @Arseny..   I should have googled the way you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the nodes not containing any text by using `[not(text())]` selector:

```
(/PARTY/PARTY_EVENT/LOCATION|/PARTY/PARTY_EVENT/LOCATION[not(text())])/text()
```